# Determine the arguments and keyword arguments of a function

Tags: python, function, parameters, functional-programming, signature

How you determine the form of a valid call to a function?

For example, say we have a function `info` that accomplishes this; `info` *might* work like this (I'm open to suggestions on whatever might be a more complete and more consistent way to represent the information returned):

```
def foo():
    pass

info(foo)
# { 'args': (), 'kwargs': {} }

def bar(a):
    pass

info(bar)
# { 'args': ('a',), 'kwargs': {} }

def baz(a, b=42):
    pass

info(baz)
# { 'args': ('a',), 'kwargs': { 'b': 42 } }

def qux(a, *args, b=42, **kwargs):
    pass

info(qux)
# { 'args': ('a',), 'kwargs': { 'b': 42 }, 'optional': {'*args', '**kwargs'} }
```

The `info` function should work for any function. I am not sure how to write an example return for every pattern: For example, `help(range.__init__)` displays

```
# __init__(self, /, *args`, **kwargs)
```

and I am not sure what the `/` means.

The return from `info` needs to be something that be computed on (with reasonable effort) for the production of arbitrary, *correct* calls to `info`'s argument, e.g., for randomized testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is already a function for this purpose, [`inspect.getfullargspec`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) which returns [`namedtuples`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(foo)
FullArgSpec(args=[], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(qux)
FullArgSpec(args=['a'], varargs='args', varkw='kwargs', defaults=None, kwonlyargs=['b'], kwonlydefaults={'b': 42}, annotations={})
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(bar)
FullArgSpec(args=['a'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(baz)
FullArgSpec(args=['a', 'b'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(42,), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

However, if you want, you can build a function from this:

```
def info(func):
    """returns function argument info"""
    specs = inspect.getfullargspec(func)
    dict_ = {}
    dict_['args'] = tuple(specs.args)
    dict_['kwargs'] = {} if specs.kwonlydefaults is None else specs.kwonlydefaults
    dict_['optional'] = set()
    dict_['defaults'] = {} if specs.defaults is None else specs.defaults
    if specs.varargs is not None:
        dict_['optional'].add(f"*{specs.varargs}")
    if specs.varkw is not None:
        dict_['optional'].add(f"*{specs.varkw}")
    if not dict_['optional']:
        dict_['optional'] = {}
    return dict_

>>> info(foo)
{'args': (), 'kwargs': {}, 'optional': {}, 'defaults': {}}

>>> info(qux)
{'args': ('a',), 'kwargs': {'b': 42}, 'optional': {'*args', '*kwargs'}, 'defaults': {}}

>>> info(bar)
{'args': ('a',), 'kwargs': {}, 'optional': {}, 'defaults': {}}

>> info(baz)
{'args': ('a', 'b'), 'kwargs': {}, 'optional': {}, 'defaults': (42,)}
```

The `42` in `baz` is not a keyword argument, it is a default one. Because while calling it is not necessary to provide the keyword `b`.

The `*` in the `help(__init__)` refers to keyword only parameters to follow, i.e. it tells the following arguments must be `keyword-only` arguments, and similarly any argument preceding `/` has to be `positional argument`, for more see [`PEP457`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0457/) , [`PEP570`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/), [`PEP3102`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

Many of these information can be obtained form the inherent [`code`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/code.html) object of the function, which has following attributes:

```
for attr in dir(qux.__code__):
    if not attr.startswith('_'):
        print(attr,':',getattr(qux.__code__, attr))

co_argcount : 1
co_cellvars : ()
co_code : b'd\x00S\x00'
co_consts : (None,)
co_filename : <ipython-input-43-6608913c4d65>
co_firstlineno : 1
co_flags : 79
co_freevars : ()
co_kwonlyargcount : 1
co_lnotab : b'\x00\x01'
co_name : qux
co_names : ()
co_nlocals : 4
co_stacksize : 1
co_varnames : ('a', 'b', 'args', 'kwargs')
```

However, these are not descriptive enough, nor easy to access and intended for internal use for python. Hence unless you absolutely need a custom function, `inspect.getfullargspec` is probably the best option.

Output of `fullargspec` being a `namedtuple` you can access different fields easily:

```
>>> argspecs = inspect.getfullargspec(qux)
>>> argspecs.args
['a']
>>> argspecs.kwonlydefaults
{'b': 42}
```

And if you want a dict you can call the [`_asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict) method of the resulting `namedtuple`:

```
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(qux)._asdict()  #gives OrderedDict
OrderedDict([('args', ['a']),
             ('varargs', 'args'),
             ('varkw', 'kwargs'),
             ('defaults', None),
             ('kwonlyargs', ['b']),
             ('kwonlydefaults', {'b': 42}),
             ('annotations', {})])
>>> dict(inspect.getfullargspec(qux)._asdict()) #call dict to get regular dict
{'args': ['a'],
 'varargs': 'args',
 'varkw': 'kwargs',
 'defaults': None,
 'kwonlyargs': ['b'],
 'kwonlydefaults': {'b': 42},
 'annotations': {}}
```

Comment: Thanks. For any other questioners out there: there is more to be found on StackOverflow when searching for [inspect.getfullargspec with the python tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+inspect.getfullargspec), _now that I know what to search for_. Thanks.